# Make the line down in parbox

Tags: parbox

Why do I get a line in the middle?

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
%%\parbox[alignment][height][inner-alignment]{width}{text}
The answer is:\parbox[c][][b]{2cm}{\hrulefill}.\par
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `\parbox[b]` instead of `\parbox[c]` should work. The first optional argument determines the vertical position of the parbox. You used `c` which means vertically centered ans is exactly what you get.

Comment: It is as simple to use `The answer is: \rule{2cm}{0.4pt}`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @leandriis,

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
The answer is:\parbox[b]{2cm}{\hrulefill}.\par
\end{document}
```

Comment: a Bernard commented, `\rule` would be the more natural command here. also the optional arguments `[][b]` do nothing (the final `b` option can only have any effect if you specify a vertical height with the second option).

Answer (score 2):

A `\parbox` is certainly not the right tool for this job.

If you want a 2cm wide rule sitting at mid height of lowercase letters, you can do

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\middlerule}[2][0.4pt]{%
  \raisebox{\dimexpr0.5ex-(#1)/2}{\rule{#2}{#1}}%
}

\begin{document}

The answer is:~\middlerule{2cm}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Or, with the `\vrule` primitive,

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\middlerule}[2][0.4pt]{%
  \vrule
    height \dimexpr0.5ex+(#1)/2\relax
    depth \dimexpr(#1)/2-0.5ex\relax
    width #2\relax
}

\begin{document}

The answer is:~\middlerule{2cm}

\end{document}
```

With either version, the input

```
The answer is:~\middlerule[1pt]{2cm}
```

would produce a 1pt thick rule.

[image]